# Win32 API ReadFile() чтение по N байт

Tags: c++, winapi

Всем доброго времени суток. Задача: Чтение файла функцией ReadFile() по N байт в цикле. Вопрос: Нужно ли каждый раз указывать позицию, с которой необходимо начинать чтение? ReadFile() где-то запоминает позицию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если читаете последовательно — нет, не надо. Вы же передаете первым параметром

```
HANDLE hFile
```

вот по этому дескриптору файла и хранится всякая служебная информация и, в частности, текущая позиция чтения из файла.